convex and differentiable imply twice differentiable
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be convex and differentiable, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all real $h$, we have : $f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+o(h^2)$.
Show that $f''(a)$ exists and $f''(a)=0$.

I have a proof which does not use the convexity assumption and I cannot find why the proof would be incorrect.
Since $f(a+h-h)=f(a+h)-hf'(a+h)+o(h^2)$ then $f'(a+h)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)+o(h^2)}{h}$.
Since $f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+o(h^2)$ then $f'(a)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)+o(h^2)}{h}$.
Therefore,
$$
\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{h}=\frac{o(h)}{h}=o(1).
$$
Hence $f''(a)$ exists and is $0$.

Why do you have $o(h^2)$ and not $o(h)$ in your Taylor series ?

it's the statement of the exercise. If o(h), I am not sure the statement of the exercise is correct.

@Ceru It is the assumption of the exercise.

The proof goes incorrect in the expansion of $f(a+h-h)$. The condition $f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+o(h^2)$ holds for a one particular $a$. It is not necessarily valid for $a+h$ (should it hold for any $a$, your proof'd be correct, and it'd also prove that $f$ is linear, much more than the problem states).
Instead, expand $f(a+h_1)$ and $f(a+h_2)$, and see what convexity says about them.
